# how can I set and access cookies in mern stack

Tags: cookies, redux

i am trying to set and access cookies in mern stack where i used express js. I tried to store the jwt token in cookies, while testing api in thunder client the token was stored in cookies successfully. But when i used axios to make request to that api i did not find the cookies in the broser application tab.
There is no error, all the functionality works fine, the problem is i am not able to set and access the cookie in frontend.

this is my app.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const errorMiddleware = require("./middleware/error");
const cors = require("cors");

const phoneRoutes = require("./routes/phone-routes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user-routes");

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/api/phones", phoneRoutes);
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);


app.use(errorMiddleware);

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/project", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(8000, () => {
      console.log("connected to database");
    });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

this is routing file for login

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("../models/user");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", async(req, res, next) =>{
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

  if (!user) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Please enter valid credentials", 401));
  }

  const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isPasswordMatched) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Please enter valid credentials", 401));
  }

  const token = await user.getJWTToken();

  res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("token", token, {
      expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
      httpOnly: true,
    })
    .json({ success: true, user, token });
})
module.exports = router;
```

this is my login action in redux using axios. And I have already tried using widthCredentials and Credentials in axios request but still got no result.

```
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });

    const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/user/login";
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };

    const { data } = await axios.post(url, { email, password }, config);


    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data.user });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
};
```

this is a user reducer file.

```
export const userReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the cookie from backend to client we need to send that cookie in response. To do that follow the below mentioned steps -

- Send the cookie back in response.
- For accesstoken prefer httponly cookie, because it is not accessible to
  client side javascript which is considered to be the secure way.
- If cookie is set as a httponly cookie then it will automatically added to
  each request.
- Set the withcredentials as true in axios instance (Client side).

```
app.post('/cookie-demo', function(req, res, next){
  res.cookie("KEY", "Value", { expires: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + (10 * 86400000)), httponly:true });
  res.status(201).json({data:null, message:"cookie set successfully."})
});
```

Learn more [here](https://medium.com/@mybytecode/what-is-jwt-how-to-implement-jwt-based-authentication-in-nodejs-b11a172f3ae7)

Comment: I am able to get cookies in my header under the network tab of devTools but not able to get cookie value in the application tab. And I am trying to log in through that cookie value and that's where I am stuck.

Comment: i tried using withcredentials too but did not get any result

Comment: Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. @ManishRai

Comment: still not getting any results.